# Objects displaced randomly after saving and re-opening

Tags: modeling, saving

I'm not sure what I have been doing wrong but sometimes when I save my file and re-open it the objects are all displaced in random rotations and locations. My most recent model has been completely scrambled.

[image: Was a robot humanoid but its all scrambled]

[image: Shows the keyframes unintentionally added]

Comment: Are you using keyframes and/or delta transformations?

Comment: Not intentionally using Keyframes as I was just modeling up to this point, but I do see under Dope Sheet there is a Bezier Curve for each object with a single keyframe showing but deleting the keyframes does nothing. Before I saved I selected all the objects and applied the rotation and scale because one or two had rotated and warped shape previously. Maybe that caused it?

Comment: The Delta's are all at zero besides the scales which are at 1.0

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure then. Usually unexplained orientations of objects upon reopening are the result of keyframes, but it's hard to tell without knowing more about your project. You can upload an example of your file here - https://blend-exchange.com/ - copy the link they give you and paste it into your question.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking the time to help. I just uploaded the file.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to fix it, but there are keyframed transformations on the objects - that likely has something to do with it, but I'm not sure how. As you said, disabling them does nothing.

Comment: That's okay. I'll just go back in and reposition them. When I do... Should I make sure there are no prior keyframes first, then reposition the objects and set their location rotation and scale? I just want the objects to maintain their transforms.

Comment: I think I am adding keyframes acccidentally and then making adjustments that don't keep or something. I had another project where if I accidentally hit the space bar it would move my pieces around. I was able to delete the keyframes on that one and the objects went back to their proper positions, but again, I had never intentionally added any keyframes... so I must be pressing something on accident.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not the expert on keyframes, as I usually keep mine nice and simple if I ever  use them - If they mess up, I start again ;)  I'll upvote the question, and hopefully someone who animates more frequently than me can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by deleting all of the keyframes, then selecting all objects in object mode and clearing their current transforms. It turns out I had Auto-Keying enabled in the Timeline by mistake which I realized when I saw the locations, rotations, and scales were orange instead of yellow.

As to why these displacements only take effect upon loading I have no idea...